# TypeScript object type with keys from other object type where the value of the key matches a specific type

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to create a type "IndexRecord" that takes a type parameter that extends an object type. The only valid keys should be a subset of the keys from the input type, where the value of T[key] extends the DocumentId type. If the key is valid, the entry should be "[key]: true", otherwise, the entry should not be allowed at all. Additionally, each entry should be optional.

This is what I have so far:

```
// Not an exact replica of KvObject and DocumentId, but contains the fundementals
type DocumentId = string | number

type Primitive = string | number | bigint | boolean

type KvValue = Primitive | Primitive[] | KvObject

type KvObject = {
    [key: string]: KvValue
}

// IndexRecord type I'm trying to define
type IndexRecord<T extends KvObject> = Partial<{
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends DocumentId ? true : never
}>

interface Data extends KvObject {
  big: bigint   // Does not conform to DocumentId
  small: number // Does conform to DocumentId
}

// This seems to behave like I want it to
const indexRecord1: IndexRecord<Data> = {
  big: true,  // Error: type 'true' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
  small: true
}

// I want this to give an error for big, not for small.
//
// Error:
// Property 'small' is incompatible with index signature
// Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
const indexRecord2: IndexRecord<Data> = {
  big: undefined, // No error
  small: true
}
```

Is it possible to specify what I wish for? To define a subset of keys where the type of T[key] is of some type, and not allow any other entries?

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDkHsBdQQwHagKYA84GNYCdkAcAbASwzlEgDNQBpANwHkAjAK2S3gQBNQARSDAK4BbZAmgBJTgBpQjAbAyQxcIggDOoaAAtkoCgK7IRygmoBQ0AJ55dfQcYncAvKDXRsqgOagAPqATCjMjYZhbWugAKHkJE0ES0ui5uHgjefgFCQdi%20skSeqrB%20jJCQBMiIoVY2NLQAanAEAomgUUQxcQk5re3xyADaALo5dEysWJXhNaNssC4A3magS6B9ANbIlgBcru5eA9t09Y3IZgC%20E9XihqgASmyQ2JwAPAAqKKjQopwaIywzAHygFwRODYOINJ4LJZrDagVSgdaWSigF77FEwyxDNCfLgaOzCUSOUAAfk02CaoG2CGQCRCp3%20oQKwQomFscGgZGxXx%20DD%207ChuU820YeQKyxAvEgyA0CBgoEUCAoDyEmkgkvshMki1cQgaBCpgWCoAlfGl8qUSuwKugavxDi15zMCrccOud0UjwAjNsrpw0O6Hs8eOy4ID5tqRUKyU0ZMawABRbDYB7bKq6ADk7ia6bhMrlcDUajyCDgjDKqs0k3TBj9FFUyE46e1al1BH10ZOjolieT2E2ZglUUgNjBllA6ZbepzRA0qkUQjw7KIZd0AHdYlpXX7UK5i%20yBLgB2AXlWs8hp3nYAWi54SyuK2nxzXkHXqY2nUoXaptwHHgAmH03XuR4nmDDkw1AAVI22Z9XwbGQJSgFAkweZtW3bM8ziAA)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] without dependence on third-party or private things like `KvObject`, `DocumentId`, or `Data`, (or at least import their definitions in the code if they are provided elsewhere).  Ideally someone could copy and paste your plaintext code here into their own IDEs and immediately see what you're seeing.

Comment: I added it to my question now. But the exact construction of these types aren't so important in itself, it's if conditionally selecting keys from an object type as I've tried can be done.

Comment: Please put the code as plaintext in your question.  A link to an external IDE doesn't count as a [mre] itself although it's great supplement to one.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3vakN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Gotcha, edited my question again. That's VERY close. I would really like it to not allow an entry of "big" at all, not even undefined.

Comment: Oh, I see `"// I want this to give an error for big, not for small."` But why?  Saying that a value can't be `undefined` means you want to change your compiler options to distinguish missing from undefined, which is probably more annoying than it's worth.  Try "I don't want to allow `undefined` in place of missing" elsewhere in TS and you're going to have a big headache.

Comment: Hmm, well I get what you mean, and I will probably just have to deal with it then. My hope was that I could keep the IndexRecord clean of any other entries than expected as I'm using it to select entries from data objects which must adhere to DocumentId, but I can do a check for it at the relevant point.

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXr2Jm) but those compiler options are .  If you really want that I could write that up but please check to make sure you want to deal with that in your TS code base before I go through the effort to do that.

Comment: Nah, that's unnecessary, thanks for your answer, I'll use the first one. I'm using Deno as well so don't want to mess with any compiler options, don't even know how to do that or if it's possible as Deno is opinionated on that.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76220543/typescript-object-type-with-keys-from-other-object-type-where-the-value-of-the-k#comment134413633_76220543) @jcalz I'm curious why you seem averse to [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes) and [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) — have you previously written about it more expressively than "it's a headache" or "" somewhere you can provide a link to? In my current view, those options improve TypeScript's core feature (safety).

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76220543/typescript-object-type-with-keys-from-other-object-type-where-the-value-of-the-k#comment134413759_76220543) You seem to know quite a lot about TypeScript, so I'm interested to hear your thoughts on those and similar stricter options.

Comment: @jsejcksn that might have been hyperbolic of me... in the alternate world where those options were part of the `--strict` standard type safety suite, I would be fine using them... any pain would have been a one-time thing migrating old code bases.  But since they're not, anyone considering this change has to decide if it's worth dealing with seemingly unrelated parts of their code base breaking, and the fact that these aren't as well-trodden since they're not part of `--strict`. The safety isn't the problem itself, it's the breakage to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the main problem with your version of `IndexRecord<T>` is that when `T` has an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), it is [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) incorrectly.  Yours is equivalent to

```
type IndexRecord<T extends KvObject> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends DocumentId ? true : never
}
```

and produces the following type for `Data`:

```
type IndexRecordData = IndexRecord<Data>
/* type IndexRecordData = {
    [x: string]: undefined;
    big?: undefined;
    small?: true | undefined;
} */
```

Note that the `string` index signature has a value type of `undefined`, meaning that no property with a string-valued key can have a defined value.  That's not what you wanted.  It also conflicts with the value type for the `small` key, which is normally not allowed to happen; indeed, if you tried to define `IndexRecordData` manually that way, you'd get an error:

```
type IndexRecordData = {
  [x: string]: undefined;
  big?: undefined;
  small?: true | undefined; // error!
  // Property 'small' of type 'true | undefined' is not assignable
  // to 'string' index type 'undefined'.
}
```

So you don't want that.

---

But why did it happen?  It's because the check `T[K] extends DocumentId ? true : never` ends up checking `KvValue extends DocumentId`, which is false.  So the type takes the false branch of the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and evaluates to just `never` (and when using the `?` [mapped type modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to turn the property optional, it gets `| undefined` added to it, at least with [the standard `--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict)).  Really you'd want `KvValue` to take *both* branches, because `KvValue` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of types, some of which are assignable to `DocumentId` and some of which are not.

One way to accomplish this is to replace your check with a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), which naturally distributes over unions.  Distributive conditional types require that the checked type be a plain type parameter; your checked type was `T[K]` which is a combination of type parameters.  So one fix would be to refactor to its own utility type like this:

```
type CheckDocId<T> =
  T extends DocumentId ? true : never;

type IndexRecord<T extends KvObject> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: CheckDocId<T[K]>;
}
```

That looks the same, but `CheckDocId<T>` is distributive in unions in `T`.  So now we have:

```
type IndexRecordData = IndexRecord<Data>;
/* type IndexRecordData = {
    [x: string]: true | undefined;
    big?: undefined;
    small?: true | undefined;
} */
```

That's a valid type, and it means that arbitrary keys will now be allowed (if you don't want this, then you might not want an index signature at all, in which case you should consider modifying `Data` so it doesn't have one), and so `small` will be allowed as well. Only `big` will be rejected:

```
let indexRecord: IndexRecord<Data>;
indexRecord = {
  big: true,  // Error: type 'true' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
  small: true
}
indexRecord = { small: true }; // okay
indexRecord = { big: undefined, small: true }; // okay
```

Note in the last example that `{big: undefined}` is allowed.  This is because, with normal `--strict` compiler options, [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) will always allow `undefined`.  If you want to change that you can look into [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) and possibly [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess), but that will affect your whole code base so I'm not going to worry about it here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-agOGvJPG8HyYj8VTDFM96KqCqIQkg0KwvC5oXmw178LeKJogCXqnpUwGRtGwJATykbPNGeHCmKgFEcyUbyqRsYqvGm5JhsQ7ZAepZ2qanjmjxnp2h2+acYW3ElsJ3q+qcZj5MEFCYLYTHPliUGTOwsb8Rs-H5MqFZ8Mgk7TooCAUI8QiaOuOIOJIoKiV2ZKBME5ZgEZGhmRZ2BWWuvBvnZnAnmYpSwKoDIRgxGz0XylHytR4UygxzGgjp37IDIbmgAAolWjycRKg6FuOJmwHAs7zoupTWbuA5CZwrYOZ2BDiQ0J6JZFfLMXmTnpaARxlhWkBLHAljyeRyWzDknhZqONoyI5LV9QNZhAA)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that does exactly what I want. This method filters out the keys of properties that do not conform to DocumentId:

```
type DocumentId = string | number

type Primitive = string | number | bigint | boolean

type KvValue = Primitive | Primitive[] | KvObject | KvObject[]

type KvObject = {
    [key: string]: KvValue
}

export type KeysThatExtend<T1, T2> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T1 as T1[K] extends T2 ? K : never]: unknown
}

export type IndexRecord<T extends KvObject> = {
  [K in KeysThatExtend<T, DocumentId>]?: true
}
```

Given the interface:

```
interface Data extends KvObject {
  big: bigint
  small: number
}
```

The only valid IndexRecord of Data is:

```
const indexRecord: IndexRecord<Data> = {
  small: true
}

// ..or empty, big = undefined is not valid
const indexRecord: IndexRecord<Data> = {}
```